# WHM Upgrade Blocked by EXIMUP

Tags: upgrade, cpanel, vps, whm, exim

I am in the middle of rebuilding my VPS and I am getting an error in WHM.

CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 virtuozzo – vps-1.........  WHM 11.34.2 (build 8)

`Reasons for blocked updates
Please correct these issues and rerun updates.
fatal: Upgrade is blocked because EXIMUP is set to 'never' in your configuration. To proceed, you can touch file '/var/cpanel/exim.unmanaged' and run the upgrade one more time. Please refer to our documentation at http://go.cpanel.net/1136UpgradeExim for more information.`

The URL for help doesn't exist.
I do not see this file in when I check for it.
I found the Exim Configuration Manager but do not see anything that matches what the error states.

I have a feeling this is fairly easy fix but I am far from an expert on VPS managing. I'm learning the hard way to put it nicely...

Does anyone know how I can clear this out so I can upgrade WHM?

I see in their documentation:
To upgrade from cPanel & WHM version 11.34 and earlier:
Touch /var/cpanel/exim.unmanaged
Run the upgrade again.

What does "Touch"mean? I tried toggling the exim option in preferences but it made no difference.

Comment: It literally means to run the command from a shell prompt 'touch /var/cpanel/exim.unmanaged'.  Not "Touch", but "touch".  This is not a setting in exim, instead this is managing WHM.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was not aware of this term. Since the file was not created I created it and put it in the directory. Now it all seems to be upgrading fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a night of fighting this I find the answer right after I post. Here is how I solved it.

Touch means to create or modify a file without actually writing to it. So in this case since the file did not exist. I created a new file in /var/cpanel/ called 'exim.unmanaged'

After placing that file in the directory I ran the updates again and it is now upgrading WHM and cPanel.

Pros know this I am sure but hopefully this will be helpful for newbi VPS admins like myself.

Comment: yes, you are correct just create a new file by: nano /var/cpanel/exim.unmanaged and save it by CTRL + O => Enter => CTRL + X. Then  run again your update.

Comment: @srapsware the easier way is to literally run `touch /var/cpanel/exim.unmanaged` as mentioned by Todd Lyons above.